# Adding multiple lines in UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I am trying to make a times table app with user's input value. Whenever I try to print result on a label, it just prints the last line and not a full table.

How can I append text in `UILabel`? Here is my code:

```
if let textBox = textField.text{
    let textBoxNum = Int(textBox)

    if let number = textBoxNum{
        if number > 0{
           let i = 1

           while i <= 20{
               label.text = "\(number) x \(i) = \(number * i)"
            }
        }
        else{
            label.text = "Please enter a positive whole number"
        }
    }
    else{
        label.text = "Please enter a positive whole number"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator = just reassigns a new value to the text of your label. You need to add on to the existing text using the Compound Assignment Operator call addition assignment operator += which will assign new value by adding it to the existing value.

```
let a:String = "Hello"      
print(a)                    // Hello
a += " World!"
print(a)                    // Hello World!
```

This same terminology will be applied to your case where you will use += on the text property of the label.

```
if let textBox = textField.text{
    let textBoxNum = Int(textBox)

    if let number = textBoxNum{
        if number > 0{
           let i = 1

           while i <= 20{
               label.text += "\(number) x \(i) = \(number * i)\n"
               // Use of compound operator here will append the text so you have
               // to use a new line escape character to print the text properly.
            }
        }
        else{
            label.text = "Please enter a positive whole number"
        }
    }
    else{
        label.text = "Please enter a positive whole number"
    }
}
```

More about operators here: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I tried using this method but it gave me following error:
Cannot convert value of type 'String?' to expected argument type 'inout String'
So, I tried label.text = label.text! +  "\(number) x \(i) = \(number * i)\n" and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Additional to the other answers (using `+=` and `\n` for line breaks):

If you use a label, you'll have to set the number of lines to zero, which will allow unlimited number of lines:

```
label.numberOfLines = 0
```

But you might better want a `UITextField` to display multi-line text, which allows the user to scroll up and down if the text gets too long. You would only have to disable the editing / keyboard popping up, something like:

```
class TheViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.theTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This is really helpful in order to enable scrolling. Thanks